# The alias of the scalar sub query is not recognized in the select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example,

```
SELECT 
    cost, 
    (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM stock) AS min_cost, 
    price - min_cost
FROM stock
```

When I execute this sql statement, I get the following error. What is the reason?

`ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'min_cost' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly use an aliased column within a main query, that needs to be generated within a subquery.

This usage is also possible as an alternative :

```
SELECT cost, 
       price - (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM stock) AS cost_diff
  FROM stock
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns produced by expressions in a query are not immediately available to the `WHERE` clause, though they may be available to the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, or `ORDER BY` clauses.

If you need to use a *named expression* in the `WHERE` clause you'll need to include your query as a "table expression" of another query.

For example:

```
select
  *,
  price - min_cost
from (
  SELECT 
    cost, 
    (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM stock) AS min_cost
  FROM stock
) x
```

You can use this strategy to produce named columns for complex expressions that need to be combined further into other complex formulas/expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the expression, alias will be not recognized

```
SELECT 
    cost, 
    (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM stock) AS min_cost, 
    price - (SELECT MIN(cost) FROM stock)
FROM stock
```